# Netbeans C++ Compiler Error

Tags: c++, windows, netbeans, mingw

Let me start by saying that I am a Windows 8 user on a HP laptop. 
So I very recently started an online course in c++ with 'c++ institute'. As recommended by them, I downloaded the MinGW/MSYS package, JDK and NetbBeans IDE version 8.0.2. 
I followed their installation instructions exactly (including updating the path directory by adding ";C:\MinGW\bin;C:\MinGW\MSYS\1.0\bin")
I am now on chapter 3 of the program and everything was going ok until I tried to compile the following code (see below)

```
/* 
 * File:   hello.cpp
 *
 * Created on 19 May 2015, 18:26
 */

#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int exp;
    int pow = 1;

    for(exp = 0; exp < 16; exp++) {
    printf("2 to the power of %d is %d\n",exp,pow);
        pow = pow*2;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

For some reason when I try to compile and run the program I get the following error messages

```
"/C/MinGW/MSYS/1.0/bin/make.exe" -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk QMAKE=         SUBPROJECTS= .build-conf
make.exe[1]: Entering directory `/c/Users/Philip/Desktop/C++ Course/Hello'
"/C/MinGW/MSYS/1.0/bin/make.exe"  -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk     dist/Debug/MinGW-Windows/hello.exe
make.exe[2]: Entering directory `/c/Users/Philip/Desktop/C++ Course/Hello'
mkdir -p build/Debug/MinGW-Windows
rm -f "build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/hello.o.d"
g++    -c -g -MMD -MP -MF "build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/hello.o.d" -o         build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/hello.o hello.cpp
mkdir -p dist/Debug/MinGW-Windows
g++     -o dist/Debug/MinGW-Windows/hello build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/hello.o 
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot     open output file dist/Debug/MinGW-Windows/hello.exe: Permission denied
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make.exe[2]: *** [dist/Debug/MinGW-Windows/hello.exe] Error 1
make.exe[2]: Leaving directory `/c/Users/Philip/Desktop/C++ Course/Hello'
make.exe[1]: *** [.build-conf] Error 2
make.exe[1]: Leaving directory `/c/Users/Philip/Desktop/C++ Course/Hello'
make.exe": *** [.build-impl] Error 2

BUILD FAILED (exit value 2, total time: 4s)
```

The code was copied and pasted directly from the course files and it seems to make sense to me. So can anybody tell me what I am doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Whoever advised you to include `C:\MinGW\MSYS\1.0\bin` in your windows PATH should be summarily hung, drawn, and quartered. The **only** sanctioned way to invoke MSYS programs is from a shell which has been started by the msys.bat script ... via a desktop or start menu shortcut, if you wish. If you adhere to this supported technique, you have no need for that inclusion in the windows PATH; having it there is likely to cause grief, eventually.

Comment: Thanks. So if I delete that directory from the path will it sort the problem, or is there further configuration needed for the compiler? sorry I am pretty much a total noob when it comes to programming

Comment: No, I don't think that having `C:\MinGW\MSYS\1.0\bin` in the windows PATH is the cause of your problem, in this instance, but it is a configuration fault. Trying to run MSYS programs from a process which has not been started from a correctly instantiated MSYS shell is unsupported by MinGW.org, and usually leads to odd, possibly intermittent failures, at some stage. When your process *is* run from a correctly instantiated MSYS shell, the shell initialization takes care of setting the PATH correctly, in the MSYS environment; it is wrong to set it in the windows environment.

Comment: @Phil Does it happen all the time or it compiles and runs fine the first time you open the program but fails afterwards?

Comment: @PetrosDrakoulis I have since given up on this set up. I am now working on a new machine using Borland, Notepad++ and Eclipse. Sorry but I cannot contribute anymore to this question

Answer (score 0):

The relevant error message is

> ```
> cannot open output file dist/Debug/MinGW-Windows/hello.exe: Permission denied
> ```

Which indicates you do not have write permission on the folder it's attempting to create `hello.exe` in. Make the `dist/Debug/MinGW-Windows` folder writable, and that error should be resolved.

Comment: Thanks. Sorry but how would I go about that?

Answer (score 0):

https://netbeans.org/community/releases/80/cpp-setup-instructions.html#compilers_windows

Try by instructions given over here.